# How to install h5py for version 1.10

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow in a python module, which is called by a c++ file. I moved to a new computer, where I installed ros again. So it works on one computer, but not on the other. There I got the following error:

```
UserWarning: h5py is running against HDF5 1.10.0 when it was built against 1.10.4, this may cause problems '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple)
```

then I did:

```
pip2.7 uninstall h5py
pip2.7 install h5py==1.10.4
```

but then I get the following error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "keyring.backend"
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h5py==1.10.4 (from versions: 2.2.1, 2.3.0b1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0b1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc2, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0, 2.10.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for h5py==1.10.4
```

It seems like there is no 1.10.4 version. What should I do?
I have to use python2.7. Also if I just let the python2.7 script run, it works. Only in conjunction with ros I get this error. But I think I take the python version from the same folder.

Thank you